# cant open jar files using double click

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface, executable-jar

I already tried jarfix and jar runner and the cmd command("javaw.exe -jar .jar" and it was written that [unable to access .jar])

here is my java version:
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

tried:
1.java -jar "C:\Path to File\myJar.jar"
result:fail

Stacktrace:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: joptsimple/OptionException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joptsimple.OptionException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are spaces in the path this can cause such a failure. Even if it is the current directory.

So write something like this:

```
java -jar "C:\Path to File\myJar.jar"
```

Otherwise it might be a permissions issue. Check the file permissions.

Comment: Looks like a JNI problem, you should have mentioned that from the start.